# Error when using NSUserDefault - swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I get this error when going back to the main view after purchasing "Remove Ads" - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When the user pays I save a bool using NSUserDefault - setBool.

When the ad loads this is the code i use to hide it -

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("viewAdsBool") {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
        self.Quote.hidden = false
    } else {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = false
    }
}
```

But when I run the app I get the error. How can I fix it?

update

This is how i set the bool -

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "viewAdsBool")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Show us the line where you set the bool in the userdefaults. Also are you doing it before you actually call it?

Comment: I call it every time the app is running, not Necessarily after i set the value